# Alter getProduct collection

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, collection

I need to alter the *equivalent* of native "**getProductCollection**", but I don't know how and where to do this.

I need the getProductCollection to look like this :

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('bio', true);
    return $collection;
}
```

this code works fine, but it's not on the catalog product page. How do I change the initial function to add my **addFieldToFilter**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to do that ( both need to be implemented using simple custom module ):

use **plugin** and modify output of getProductionCollection like **aftergetProductionCollection()**

or **Override** Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

in function **getProductCollection()** add your condition

Comment: I think the second solution is what I need, I'll check asap and I'll come back to you.